# xCode Stripping extended attributes failed / xattr

Tags: python, xcode, xattr

When I try to upload an app to the app store I get the following error:

Stripping extended attributes failed.
"/usr/bin/xattr -crs /var/folders/t2/fjp18t212bdc6kgb3pjzk81m0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.ZBT/Root/Payload/testvgd.app" exited with a non-zero status. The /usr/bin/xattr tool may be damaged.

When I try to run this tool /usr/bin/xattr from command-line I get:
"pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'xattr==0.6.4' distribution was not found and is required by the application"

Where and how can I add this xattr distribution? I downloaded it from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xattr/0.6.4, but when I try to install this, I get: error: package directory 'xattr' does not exist.

Is there a fix or workaround for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was afraid I had to clean re-install of Mac, however: an update of MacOS was enough to solve the error in xattr

I hope I save someone the trouble of a clean install with this answer :)

Answer (score -2):

I restart the MAC computer solved the problem.